# Fix supporting edge

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, edges, topology

How do I turn this tri into a nice supporting edge quad?

[image: Edge Loop problem]

And maybe how do I prevent this strange loop cuts?

Comment: Not sure if I underdstand the question(?)
e and (delet) vertical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select both adjacent faces (holding down **Shift** key) and make into one. Delete [**X**] > Limited Dissolve.
2. Initiate a loop-cut. [**Ctrl + R**] (PS: Don't press any mouse button until you would complete the following next step)
3. While you slide the loop, press [**E**]ven and you may need to press [**F**]lip as well to make the loop run parallel to the end you are sliding the edge to.